# Downloading data sets during installation

Tags: qgis, data, installation

I can successfully install QGIS 2.8.1 on a Windows 7 machine but I get an error when downloading the Carlina, South Dakota and Alska data sets. The error message is http/1.0 504 Gateway Timeout. Looks to me like as I am behind a firewall, I need to supply login credentials. But how would I do that?

Comment: From where you download the maps or map data? Is there a way to get more information about the downloading. I download maps from 3rd party websites as geojson for instance.

Comment: During the installation itself, there is an option to install the data sets. As a result, if you click on the check the boxes (signifying that they should be installed) they should be then downloaded and installed. The installer actually shows a dialog box stating that they are about to be downloaded and installed but fails with the error mentioned.

Comment: Ohh okay, long time ago I installed QGIS =) And is there no alternative to download it now? I mean for sure it's way easier to install it be QGIS installation but I don't think that's easy to fix. So yeah already searched for the data on the net?

Answer (score 1):

The **[Getting Started](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html#sample-data)** manual contains some links on obtaining sample data which I *think* are the same datasets when installing QGIS. The following is the direct link for a sample dataset:

http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/data/qgis_sample_data.zip

**GRASS** also has some datasets based in North Carolina (cannot remember if it's the same dataset):

http://grass.osgeo.org/download/sample-data/

Hope this helps!